ffmpeg convert h.265 to h.264 w/lossless quality
I'm converting h.265 to h.264 but the output quality is not that good, especially if there is a lot on the screen, gets very blocky.
My command is below. What can I add/remove to keep original quality but convert to h.264? Also, please tell me if my command line is way to long and there are unnecessary flags causing the issue. Thank you
ffmpeg.exe -i "http://StreamUrl location" -hls_allow_cache 1 -map_metadata -1 -threads 2 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map -0:s -codec:v:0 libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset superfast -crf 20 -b:v 1200000 -maxrate 1200000 -bufsize 2698344 -profile:v high -level 41 -aspect 640:360 -s 1280x720 -sc_threshold 0 -codec:a:0 aac -strict experimental -ac 2 -ab 96000 -hls_time 6 -start_number 0 -hls_list_size 20 -hls_flags delete_segments -fps_mode auto -y C:\temp\temp.m3u8
Edit: Also, I'm using this flag at the beginning now -err_detect ignore_err
Any way to have ffmepg ignore the below errors and just keep trying?
I/O error
Error opening input files: Server returned 403 Forbidden (access denied)

Server returned 403 Forbidden (access denied) how are you getting ANY output?

I think you probably want at least 2mbit/s bitrate for 1280x720

That 403 only happens for a few seconds, so I would like for ffmpeg just to keep trying instead of stopping. How do I force 2mbit/s bitrate?

How do I force 2mbit/s bitrate? how did you force less than that? Do you know the bitrate of the source? perhaps try NOT setting the bitrate at all

Oh, is that what this is doing? -b:v 1200000 -maxrate 1200000

Should I just leave that flag out?

yes, leave it out, or set it to 2mbit (though, looking at some 720p videos I have, 3.5mbit may be better - that's why you should check the source bitrate, and probably match that - is that what this is doing? -b:v 1200000 what did you think that was doing?

Ok, I'll leave that out. idk, I got that command online so not really sure what any of the commands are doing :) Anything else I don't really need in there?

to be honest, I don't know what half of that does, my ffmpeg needs are much simpler :p

There is no such thing is losless conversion to h264. I assume you mean 'with minimal' loss. Drop as many settings as you can to start. ffmpeg -i "StreamUrl location" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mkv This transcodes the video to x264 and leaves the audio alone. -crf determines quality, try 14 to 18. -preset sets encoding speed/quality ratio, ... -b:v value sets variable bitrate with a target value, -maxrate sets maximum bitrate etc etc FFMpeg has great documentation, look up what each option does before using it.

Ok, thanks for the info gang. Is there a flag I can use that will ignore the below errors and just have ffmpeg keep trying? I've been using these at the front of the stream url (-multiple_requests 1 -err_detect ignore_err) but still get - Error opening input files: I/O error and Error during demuxing: I/O error

Unfortunately, i cant help you with ignoring the network errors :( You could just use an offline h265 (or anything really) clip to test on and see what different settings result in.
